# Encode the string "tamilnadu" in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I want to encode the string "tamilnadu" and the output is like "dGFtaWxuYWR1"

```
str = "tamilnadu";
print str.encode('base64','strict') //dGFtaWxuYWR1
```

But when I am encode the string its  shows an error like this

```
'base64' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to handle arbitrary codecs
```

I tired all the encoding techniques, but the output for the sting is not like this encode value "dGFtaWxuYWR1"

How can I encode the string in python 3.4

Comment: Did you try using `codecs.encode`?

Comment: Is this Python 3 ? If yes, then shouldn't print be called like print("something")

Comment: You should use the `base64` module.

Comment: when I am using codecs the encode string  is not correct

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use base64 library

```
    import base64
    c="tamilnadu"
    c=base64.b64encode(bytes(c, 'utf-8')) // b'dGFtaWxuYWR1'
    c1=base64.b64decode(c) 
    c=str(c).replace("'","")  // bdGFtaWxuYWR1
    print("Encode",c[1:])       // dGFtaWxuYWR1 
    c1=str(c1).replace("'","") // b'tamilnadu'
    print("Decode=",c1[:1]) // tamilnadu
```

After encode you have replace the `'` and first character  `b`

Answer (score 3):

You need `base64` module

```
import base64
base64.b64encode(bytes('tamilnadu', 'utf-8'))
```

Also, don't use `str` as a variable name - its a keyword in python which represents string type.

Comment: I tired already, its working  when I encode the string the encode sting should like this "dGFtaWxuYWR1" .While using this method the output like this "b'dGFtaWxuYWR1'"

Comment: @Rajendranbala It's essentially the same. The `b` at the front means it's a byte literal instead of a string type. See [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6269765/2745495).

Comment: @Coder It's funny how this solution did not work, but the accepted answer with an identical solution (but with broken code) posted 40 minutes after this one did.

Answer (score -3):

You need base64 module

```
import base64
base64.b64encode(bytes('tamilnadu', 'utf-8'))
```

Also, don't use str as a variable name - its a keyword in python which represents string type.

Comment: This is an **exact** duplicate of the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54138560/2745495).